# Random people are trying to join my server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

I host a Whitelisted Minecraft server and recently we've set up a domain name and connected to that using an A-Name DNS record. As of that point in time, which was about October of 2015, I've noticed a lot of random people trying to join my server. From all around the world. My whitelist doesn't let them in, but the logs show a lot of people trying to join. Earlier today I've set up a commandblock based Whitelist and disabled the one Minecraft provides to see if it were advertisement bots. This turns out to be false, but my problem is still occuring.

Are there any other server admins having this issue and if so, Have you fixed it and how? My Multicraft-chat looks a bit weird with all these random names in them.

13-02-2016 > EDIT:

After turning off the whitelist off the server and making a command-block based one, there were only 5 more joins and then it stopped. The problem is solved, however I do not know why it stopped when there was no whitelist. The whitelist is now turned on again and there is still no sign of any random requests to the server.

Comment: Just to clarify: they are only *trying* to join the server and aren't actually somehow getting past the whitelist?

Comment: They are not getting past the whitelist but the logs are still clearly indicating that there are people commonly getting denied by the whitelist.

Comment: Possibly someone noticed that there was a server running on port 25565 and added it to all sorts of server lists.

Comment: I edited the question to include your comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the issue; someone's trying to join, but can't.  Your logs indicate it, but that's the point of logs.  What's the problem?

Comment: I'm asking of there are other people who are experiencing the same issue, and if they have solved it.

Comment: Again, what is the problem you are facing?  People attempting to join your server and not being able to doesn't really seem to be a problem.  That's working as intended.

Comment: Are you using mods (such as Craftbukkit)?

Comment: @Frank If I've interpreted the question correctly, the problem seems to be that the OP has join attempts to their server, which is unlisted (by them), and that the OP wants to know how these people can find their server (which I covered in my previous comment, and am waiting for the OP to confirm so I can write an answer for it). In my opinion it's a decent question, as not everyone knows that some Minecraft mods report usage to a central server.

Comment: @cybermonkey The server is completely vanilla, appart from the fact that we use MultiCraft to allow web-based console access. MultiCraft does not touch the jar file in any way or change any gameplay features.

Comment: Interesting. Have you listed it anywhere (such as on GameTracker.com)?

Comment: @cybermonkey I myself or one of the other members have not reported the domain name or IP Adress anywhere. We do not have modified clients appart from some of us using OptiFine.

Comment: You are hosting a server. Im Guessing to play with other people. Are the other people giving out the IP not knowing your server is white listed?

Answer (score 1):

If you bought a server, it might just be that that port/ip combination was used before for someone else's server. They might still have the IP and don't know the server is down.

I wouldn't worry too much about these people. The worst that can happen is some console spam.

Answer (score 0):

I Think that your issue is simply people using cracked alts on your server and are not able to log in, I am having the same problem however: My Server is not Whitelisted therefore, it is obvious that people are trying to login to my server with cracked minecraft or they are hackers trying to get into the server using Server Finder.

Answer (score -3):

go to the server text file and find something like *online true* change the true to *false* then restart the server and they will not be able to join! (This only works if you howst your server yourself)

Comment: What is it that that you're changing when you sent this variable to false? Some more information as to "why" this answer works is needed.